# How to generate the sum of values

Tags: jquery

My HTML code :

```js
$(":checkbox").change(function() {    
  var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { 
    return $(this).next().text(); 
  }).get();

  var myVal = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { 
    return ($(this).attr('data-marks'));
  }).get();

  var myPoint = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { 
    var sum = 0;
    var count = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-marks'));
    sum = sum + count;
    return sum;
  }).get();

  $("#myDiv, #myTop").html(arr.join('<br><br>'));
  $('#myVal').html(myVal.join('<br><br>'));
  $('#totalGrade').text(myPoint); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><input id="c1" data-marks="20" type="checkbox" /><label for="c1">abc</label></li>
<li><input id="c1" data-marks="15" type="checkbox" /><label for="c1">xyz</label></li>
<li><input id="c1" data-marks="30" type="checkbox" /><label for="c1">pqr</label></li>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div id="myMarks"></div>
<div id="total"></div>
```

Here, I am copying the content(i.e. abc,xyz,pqr) and marks(20,15,30) relative to input checkbox into another div.While I am trying to get the respective sum of marks into the third div(i.e. total), it is coming up as a string. I am getting value as 201530 during checkbox event.
 What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the total using `map` and a variable `total` :

```
$(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { 
    total+=parseFloat($(this).attr('data-marks'));
})
```

Append total to `#total` :

```
$('#total').text(total);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(":checkbox").change(function() {    
  var total=0;

  var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { 
    return $(this).next().text(); 
  }).get();

  $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { 
    total+=parseFloat($(this).attr('data-marks'));
  })

  $("#myDiv, #myTop").html(arr.join('<br><br>'));
  $('#total').text(total); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><input id="c1" data-marks="20" type="checkbox" /><label for="c1">abc</label></li>
<li><input id="c1" data-marks="15" type="checkbox" /><label for="c1">xyz</label></li>
<li><input id="c1" data-marks="30" type="checkbox" /><label for="c1">pqr</label></li>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div id="myMarks"></div>
<div id="total"></div>

<div id="myVal"></div>
<div id="totalGrade"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.